# Datatables pagination and server-side processing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I followed these instruction: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html
But I don't get the pagination (nor in bJQuery mode nor classic). Everything is working fine (search, ordering, ...) but I can't get the pagination.

Is there something I'm missing ?

Here the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').dataTable( {
                bJQueryUI : true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
                sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource": "/returnjson"
    } );
} );
```

Thank you!

Edit:
I wrap my parameters in quotation marks. Thanks.
dgw, this is changing nothing. That I want is that the paging buttons interact with my serverside code:

```
/* 
* Paging
*/
$sLimit = " LIMIT 100";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = " LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}
```

Thanks for your help

Edit 2:
I tried with both datatables/demo_table.css and datatables/demo_table_jui.css but this change nothing.

Thanks again !

Comment: Make sure you wrap your parameter names in quotation marks. `"bJQueryUI"` and `"sPaginationType"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My iTotalDisplayRecords was not set correctly (Total records, after filtering).
Source: http://datatables.net/usage/server-side

Comment: For the next person who finds them self here: iTotalDisplayRecords is the total number of records in the DB (not the total amount to be displayed on each page) ...after any filters.

Comment: @YarsRevenge13 - I feel like Indiana Jones sometimes, spelunking for documention such as yours. It's like a warning to the others...

Answer (score 1):

Specify for example

```
"sDom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">'
```

within your call to `dataTable`. This should show the pagination.

For more information have a look at the [parameter reference of datatables](http://datatables.net/ref) especially the part about `sDom`.